# Automatically uploading a file to Google Drive File Stream with a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, webclient, google-drive-shared-drive

I have made a Windows service that;

1. Downloads a CSV file from a regularly updated internal database through a WebClient every hour.
2. Put that CSV file into a designated folder.

   - In the original test case, it was put into a local folder on my desktop (C:).
   - The test case worked perfectly.
3. The CSV would replace the old file with the newly downloaded one with the same name.

As listed above. This works perfectly on a local folder. However, we intend for it to work through Google Drive File Stream. As we have a Google Sheet that manipulates and sought the data for us for any CSV file that is under the given name.

This is the current method of downloading and placing the file.

```
public void CSVDownload()
    {
        string url = @"YOUR_CSV_URL_HERE";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_STREAM_FOLDER_HERE\NAME.csv"); 

        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object CSVDownload, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("CSV File (NAME.csv) downloaded"); 
        }
    }
```

My question is why can't I currently automatically upload a file to Google Drive File Stream through a Windows Service? Is it because Google Drive File Stream requires certain permissions or actions? Is it because the drive is "virtual" and not physical (H:)? Below is the folder I am trying to upload to in Google Drive File Stream (H:\My Drive\Test).

[image: Google Drive File Stream]

The code also runs through completely as the log files show that the methods are used. However, there seems to be some block between the download and placing of the CSV file in a Google Drive File Stream folder.

**Update:** There has been little progress so far. One of my colleagues maybe suggests that there needs to be some sought of user permission to push. Like a username and password. If this is true does anyone know how I could achieve this?

**Update #2:** In the 'Registry Editor' I found some interesting info.

1. Press Windows + R
2. Type regedit.exe
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> SOFTWARE -> Google -> DriveFS -> Share

[image]

As you can see there are two values. '`MountPoint = H`' is obviously the drive letter it is mapped to and '`ShellIpcPath = \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user.name_shell`' which might be useful. I played around with ShellcpPath but to no prevail.

**Update #3:** @Ben Voigt mentioned to use `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` to see if the drive is found by the service. I run the code and it looks like it does exist.
Here is what the console spit out:

```
Drive H:\
  Drive type: Fixed
  Volume label: Google Drive File Stream
  File system: FAT32
  Available space to current user:    15987068928 bytes
  Total available space:              15987068928 bytes
  Total size of drive:                16106127360 bytes
```

As you can see it exists however it uses `File system: FAT32` instead of `File system: NTFS` which all my other drives use (C:),(D:),etc. So it seems that only Google Drive File Stream uses FAT32.

**Test Case:**

Works perfectly when placing the CSV files into a local folder.

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\Test\designtasks.csv");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\Test\designjobs.csv");
```

[image]

Does not work when placing into a Google Drive File Stream folder.

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"H:\My Drive\Test\designtasks.csv");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"H:\My Drive\Test\designjobs.csv");
```

[image: enter imagription here]

To clarify about the test case. I am actually getting two CSV files. However, the code is basically the same. So I only mention getting one in my original question to keep it cleaner and more straightforward.

Comment: so the file is downloaded to H:\My Drive\Test but not uploaded / synced with Drive?

Comment: @kennyzx the file doesn't exist at all. It runs through the method to download and upload however the file does not show up in the file path, nor anywhere else in the computer. I know the method works as it works on local drive folders. It just seems to get lost somewhere between the method and the Google Drive Stream folder.

Comment: Drive mapped to the Windows network redirector, as well as via `subst`, are user specific.  Probably your mapped Google Drive virtual drive is user-specific as well.  Then your service runs inside a different user context... The fact that your found relevant registry entries within `HKCU` certainly supports this possibility.

Comment: Have the service write a list of the drives it sees (`DriveInfo.GetDrives()`) to what you are calling a "local text file", compare to the same results you get running an ordinary application.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have made an update #3 with your suggestion and got some interesting info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! It might not be optimal for all cases however it works in my case.

Here is what I did;

1. Make a project installer with [InstallerProjects.vsiz](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). Obviously, if you are using a different version of VS, this might change. Some of the older version already come with it installed and the newer versions do not automatically include it. You will have to also find the correlating version as the one linked is for VS2017. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-add-installers-to-your-service-application) is a tutorial on how to implement an installer on a windows service.
2. Once you have implemented the installer, right click on serviceProcessInstaller1 (or whatever you decided to call it) and select properties.
3. In the properties window, look a for the 'Account' field and set it to 'User'.
   [image: serviceProcessInstaller1 Properties]
4. Save and build you project. That's it.

**What does's this actually do?** In plain English; It basically makes the service impersonate a user so it can read and write files on the system.

---

When installing on a different computer from which the service was built on, 'Windows Defender Shield' will block the service from installing. This is just Windows bring cautious. Obviously, if you built the service without ill intent this will not harm your computer.

To continue installation click "More info" on the 'Windows Defender Shield' screen and click "Run anyway".
[image: Windows Defender Shield]

Before the Service finishes installing, it will stall and ask for user information. In most use cases, giving it your own user information ill suffice.

[image: Installation User Information]

If you are a user on a domain or anything along those lines. You will need to add the domain prefix to the 'Username' field. `Example: DOMAIN\user.name`.